# How to add hilt dependency in sub module attach it to main module

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt, multi-module

Hi anyone help  solve this issue submodule has Hilt dependency. I wanted to add to main module getting this error
Application class annotated with @HiltAndroidApp has to be defined in an android application project
[Hilt]

> 

```
 class YogaApplicatoin :Application(){
}
```

> Sub module has Hilt dependency as submodule has application class defined as

```
      @HiltAndroidApp
class BaseApplication: Application(){
```

}

> if i want to add as module i am getting
> > error
>
> Main app module has Application class which is annotated with
> @HiltAndroidApp .sub module also has application class defined

this is sub module

`@HiltAndroidApp class BaseApplication : Application() { }` 
where as main app module has

`class YogaApplication :Applicaiton(){ }`

I tried to import sub module containing hilt dependency in main module .i wanted to call class in submodule from main module

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.